# Where is the Search engine on the new StackExchange Mathematica site?

Tags: discussion, support

In the new site, I cannot find the search machine. Where is it?

Comment: This should be posted on the meta site. The search bar is top-right to the Mathematica SE logo, to the right of the Stack Exchange logo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I see.  Is your layout missing the **Search on Mathematica...** box?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I could not notice it.